# C++ program with base class, abstract class and derived class, in main function use all the related data and methods

Tags: c++, class, oop, abstract-class, virtual-functions

The problem says: *Define a class Record that stores the data related to a melody (artist, title, duration).
An abstract class (Playlist) contains as private variable a pointer to an array of records. 
The pointer is initialized in the constructor by a memory allocation process 
(the number of records is defined by the user). 
The class contains setter and getter methods for each of a record’s fields and an abstract method (pure virtual) that sorts the records array according to a criteria
coded in the received parameter (1=sorting by title, 2=sorting by artist, 3=sorting by duration).
The abstract method is implemented inside another class (PlaylistImplementation) that inherits the Playlist class.
In the main() function, instantiate the PlaylistImplementation class and initialize and use all the related data and methods.*

I wrote the code but i have 49 errors, the main problem is with class Record that it has no default constructor and it can't use the "aux" object i used in class PlaylistImplementation.

```
//AbstractClass.h

#pragma once
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#include"Header.h"

class Playlist
{
protected:
    Record* r;
    int n;
public:
    Playlist(int nn)
    {
        nn = n;
        r = new Record[n];
    }
    void init()
    {
        char t[20], a[30];
        int d;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            cout << "Song " << i + 1 << " :";
            cout << "Title:";
            cin >> t;
            r[i].set_Title(t);
            cout << "Artist:";
            cin >> a;
            r[i].set_Artist(a);
            cout << "Duration (in sec):";
            cin >> d;
            r[i].set_Duration(d);
        }
    }
    void setRecord(Record rr, int n) //setter
    {
        r[n] = rr;
    }
    Record getRecord(int n) //getter
    {
        return r[n];
    }
    virtual void ord(int c, int n) = 0; //pure virtual function
};
```

The derived class:

```
//Playlist.h

#include"AbstractClass.h"
//#include"Header.h"   //i have errors if i include the header.h file too
using namespace std;

class PlaylistImplementation :public Playlist
{
public:
    PlaylistImplementation(int n) :Playlist(n) {}
    void display(int n)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            cout << "\nTitle: " << r[i].get_Title();
            cout << "\nArtist: " << r[i].get_Artist();
            cout << "\nDuration: " << r[i].get_Duration() << " seconds";
        }
    }
    void ord(int c, int n)
    {
        switch (c)
        {
        case 1:
        {
            char s1[20], s2[30];
            cout << "\nAlphabetical order of Titles:\n ";
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                for (int j = i + 1; n - 1; j++)
                {
                    strcpy_s(s1, 20, r[i].get_Title());
                    strcpy_s(s2, 30, r[i].get_Title());
                    if (strcmp(s1, s2) > 0)
                    {
                        Record aux;
                        aux = r[i];
                        r[i] = r[j];
                        r[j] = aux;
                    }

                }
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {

            char s1[20], s2[30];
            cout << "\nAlphabetical order of Artists:\n ";
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                for (int j = i + 1; n - 1; j++)
                {
                    strcpy_s(s1, 20, r[i].get_Artist());
                    strcpy_s(s2, 30, r[i].get_Artist());
                    if (strcmp(s1, s2) > 0)
                    {
                        Record aux;
                        aux = r[i];
                        r[i] = r[j];
                        r[j] = aux;
                    }

                }
            break;
        }
        case 3:
        {

            char d1, d2;
            cout << "\nAscending order of duration:\n ";
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                for (int j = i + 1; n - 1; j++)
                {
                    d1 = r[i].get_Duration();
                    d2 = r[j].get_Duration();
                    if (d1 > d2)
                    {
                        Record aux;
                        aux = r[i];
                        r[i] = r[j];
                        r[j] = aux;
                    }
                }
            break;
        }
        default:
            cout << "\nEnter 1,2 or 3 key\n";
            break;
        }

    }
};
```

The Record class:

```
//Header.h


#include"AbstractClass.h"
#include"Playlist.h"

class Record
{
private:
    char artist[20];
    char title[30];
    int duration;
public:
    Record(char* a, char* t, int d)
    {
        *artist = *a;
        *title = *t;
        duration = d;
    }
    //setters
    void set_Artist(char* a)
    {
        strcpy_s(artist, 20, a);
    }
    void set_Title(char* t)
    {
        strcpy_s(title, 30, t);
    }
    void set_Duration(int d)
    {
        duration = d;
    }
    //getters
    char* get_Artist()
    {
        return artist;
    }
    char* get_Title()
    {
        return title;
    }
    int get_Duration()
    {
        return duration;
    }

};
```

The main():

```
//Source.cpp

#include"AbstractClass.h" //abstract class
#include"Playlist.h" //derived class
#include"Header.h"

int main()
{
    int n;
    cout << "\nEnter nr of records:";
    cin >> n;
    PlaylistImplementation ob(n);
    ob.init();
    int c;
    cout << "\nEnter a key in order to organize the playlist:";
    cin >> c;
    ob.ord(c, n);
    cout << "\nThe ordered list:";
    ob.display(n);

}
```

I tried to put a constructor to record class but didn't solve anything

Errors:
[image: Errors from the code]

[image: errors]

Comment: [“It’s not working”](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) is not a sufficient description of a programming problem. _You_ must specify what exactly is wrong and limit your question to a single problem.

Comment: Please share with us your erros; this help us.

Comment: @SorcererApprentice  i shared the errors too

Comment: @vivi25-5. I look it. My answer should help you.

Answer (score 1):

You never instantiate a Record class for aux identifier (error):

```
if (d1 > d2) {
  Record aux;
  aux = r[i];
  r[i] = r[j];
  r[j] = aux;
}
```

Because you never instantiate Record, C++ attempts to call the default constructor, but it doesn't exists, so c++ crashed.

You attempt to instantiate Record class like and array (error):

```
r = new Record[n];
```

By the way, if you want to use [] operator you have to overload it.

Comment: it's instantiated in class Playlist as an array

Comment: It isn't ad array, and it doesn't have operator[] overloading.